# How to install the xampp and moodle in mac os x?

Tags: macos, command-line, xampp, moodle

I need help to install moodle in mac with xampp. I don't know how to install it. Please help how to install these tools in my mac via command line or anything else..

Answer (score 4):

first download the xampp from http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-macosx.html#849

```
$ wget -c http://www.apachefriends.org/download.php?xampp-osx-1.8.2-2-installer.dmg
```

→ install it

```
$ hdiutil mount xampp-osx-version-number.dmg
$ cd /Volumes/xampp_mounted_directroy
$ sudo cp -Rv xampp_app_file.app /Application
```

don't forget to detatch the mounted volume

```
$ hdiutil detach <path-to-mountpoint>
```

and

```
$ cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs
```

→ then clone the git repo there

```
$ git clone git://git.moodle.org/moodle.git                       
$ cd moodle
$ git branch -a                                                   
$ git branch --track MOODLE_25_STABLE origin/MOODLE_25_STABLE     
$ git checkout MOODLE_25_STABLE
```

→ Now fire up the xampp and link localhost

OK, its done now